# ClassCastException in a Widget

Tags: android

I am starting in the widget for android world. I have this layout, named "widget.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/icono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

It simply a button, as you can see. This is the configuration xml of the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minWidth="72dip"
android:minHeight="72dip"
android:updatePeriodMillis="7000"
android:label="Widget_azafata"
/>
```

This is the class extending AppWidgetProvider, as is, it is untouched:

```
public class WidgetAppProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {


    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}


   }
```

And this is the configuration Activity:

```
public class WidgetConfig extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageButton boton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icono);
            //stuff here
      }
```

And the lines in the manifest:

```
<receiver 

        android:name=".WidgetAppProvider"
        android:label="Widget_azafata">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 

            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_azafata_xml"   />


    </receiver>
```

Well, i launch the widget and shows this Exception:

```
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.publidirecta.Azafata/com.publidirecta.Azafata.WidgetAppProvider}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.publidirecta.Azafata.WidgetAppProvider
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.publidirecta.Azafata.WidgetAppProvider
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-04 10:21:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

It shows no line of error, simply the class where the exception is launched. And i don't know why this Exception is launched. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Are you declaring your `Activity` in manifest?

and you should switch the sequence of lines in `onCreate()` like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  // this should be first call
setContentView(R.layout.main);    
ImageButton boton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icono);
```

Comment: Nope, my Activity wasn't declared in the manifest. The tutorial I was following didn't mention that. And did the switching. Thank you Adil!

Comment: So, Actually you were doing 3 mistakes :p, 1. declaration of Activity, 2) Switching the sequence, 3) calling the wrong layout.

Comment: Yes... but im now calling the correct layout, have the Activity included in the Manifest, and did the switching you said... and im still getting the same exception :(

Comment: are you sure you are providing the correct layout in `<meta-data>` tag of receiver. Does this `widget_azafata_xml.xml` exist?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minWidth="72dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="7000"
    android:label="Widget_azafata"
    /> That is the content of widget_azafata_xml.xml

Comment: It's a bit strange, in the Eclipse emulator throws exception but in my mobile don't crash, it does nothing, but dont crash.

Answer (score 1):

I Think your XML name is "widget.xml", but you are calling main.xml in activity.you have to change SetContentView(R.layout.widget);

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you are calling `startActivity()` to start `WidgetAppProvider`. `WidgetAppProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, not an `Activity`.

Comment: Im not calling startActivity in any place in MY code. I don't know if it is automatically called by the SDK.